# How to integrate skylink in react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, skylink, temasys

I am using [Skylink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/skylinkjs) for video calling and I want to use in a react project. I know how to use it with Vanilla JavaScript as their demo project is at [codepen](https://codepen.io/temasys/pen/GogabE) 
But when I try to use it with react I am getting some errors. Here is how I tried:

1. Installed the package from npm using Yarn.
2. Imported the package `import SkyLink from 'skylinkjs'`
3. Then called the function constructor `const skylink = new SkyLink();`
   But I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_skylinkjs___default.a is not a constructor`

If I try to import like this:

`import {SkyLink} from 'skylinkjs';
const skylink = new SkyLink();`

then the error is

`Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_skylinkjs__.SkyLink is not a constructor`

and If I try to import all from the module and then call the function costructor:

`import * as SkyLink from 'skylinkjs';
const skylink = new SkyLink();`

the error will be this `Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_skylinkjs__ is not a constructor`

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. Either of the following would work.

```
import { Skylink } from 'skylinkjs';
const skylink = new Skylink();
```

or

```
import skylinkjs from 'skylinkjs';
const skylink = new skylinkjs.Skylink();
```